# Sonar Issue - Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, promise, sonarqube

Sonar is showing an error for below code and I can't figure out how to fix it. Does anyone know if this is an exception to the rule or how can I refactor this?

Error: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Error Description:

> Promises need to be resolved or awaited to return the expected value, otherwise, they return the promise object.
>
> Unresolved promises:
>
> Forgetting to await a promise is a frequent mistake. There are places where the use of a promise object is confusing or unclear because the developer forgot to resolve it.
>
> This rule forbids returning promises where another type is expected such as in:
>
> conditionals
> void returns
> spread operators

Code:

```
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      await Promise.all(promises).finally(async () => {
        await Storage.clearSession();
        await Storage.clearToken();
      });
      resolve("success");
    });
```

I've tried the suggested fixes from Sonar but these either caused my tests to break or didn't resolve the error.

Comment: Does this parse?  I see what looks like an extra `}` and some other stuff on the last line. `Promise.all` returns a promise, so wrapping it in a new promise is wasteful.

Comment: @danh I've fixed it now, added too much in the snippet sorry about that

Comment: Why is that a `new Promise` at all? Just `return Promise.all(...).then(() => "success")`.

Comment: I think that's fixed it - I changed the code to just return Promise.all(promises).. etc and the error is gone and tests are passing

Answer (score -1):

You need to type your wrapping function correctly. You have void as a return type but it needs to be undefined:

```js
function yourFunction(promises: Promise<unknown>[]): void {
    // fails because your above return type is void and not Promise<string>
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      await Promise.all(promises).finally(async () => {
        await Storage.clearSession();
        await Storage.clearToken();
      });
      resolve("success");
    });
}
```

---

To solve this simply change your types around:

```js
// since we return undefined our return type must be undefined
async function yourFunction(promises: Promise<unknown>[]): Promise<undefined> { 
    await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      await Promise.all(promises).finally(async () => {
        await Storage.clearSession();
        await Storage.clearToken();
      });
      resolve("success");
    });

    // in TS, return is always going to return undefined
    return;
}
```

---

Another, cleaner way to do the above logic:

```js
// since we return undefined our return type must be undefined
async function yourFunction(promises: Promise<unknown>[]): Promise<undefined> {
    await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    await Storage.clearSession();
    await Storage.clearToken();

    // in TS, return is always going to return undefined
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have to return a Promise<string> though, I don't want it to return undefined.

Comment: @cligg123 then just change the return types from undefined to string, and return "success" :)